# Stop eslint complaining about dynamic imports in create-react-app app

Tags: eslint, create-react-app

The eslint rules that ship natively in CRA seem to not like dynamic imports. So in

```
...
// Lazy load
const Login = lazy(() => import('./Login'));
const LoggedInHome = lazy(() => import('./LoggedInHome'));
...
```

both of those `import`s get highlighted (though eslint isn't giving an error message).

What's the least disruptive way to fix this?

I'm running eslint 8.1.0 and react-scripts 5.0.0.

*Probably* this doesn't matter, but in case it does, eslint is run via ALE on vim.

**Edit:** My eslint config is as follows:

```
<my project>
├── .eslintrc.json
└─┬ views
  └─┬ <my react app>
    ├── package.json
    └── src
    ...
```

I don't believe there are any eslint configurations either further up or down the tree.

**package.json:**

```
...
  "eslintConfig": {
    "extends": [
      "react-app",
      "react-app/jest"
    ]
  },
...
```

**.eslintrc.json:**

```
{
    "env": {
        "browser": true,
        "node": true,
        "commonjs": true,
        "es2021": true
    },
    "plugins": [
    "prettier"
    ],
    "extends": [
        "eslint:recommended",
        "plugin:json/recommended",
        "prettier"
    ],
    "parserOptions": {
        "ecmaVersion": 2020,
        "sourceType": "module"
    },
    "rules": {
    }
}
```

Comment: Could you please share your ESLint configuration?

Comment: @Akasha , added to the question. Cheers.

Comment: Thanks. Before I suggest a possible solution, are you using Vim as code editor?

Comment: Yes. I'm old :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Does the same highlight happen in other code editors?

It might be a Vim situation.

Which syntax plugin for JavaScript are you using in Vim?

Some of the older syntax plugins don't do well with modern ES features.

Try plugins like [YAJS](https://github.com/othree/yajs.vim) along with [ES.Next.Syntax](https://github.com/othree/es.next.syntax.vim).

ES.Next.Syntax supports dynamic imports, and works with YAJS.

Comment: Actually, was already using YAJS. Hadn't realised I needed the extra add-on.